# Donde colocar mis DbSet<> en mi proyecto con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

Bueno esta tal vez sea una pregunta tonta pero me gustaría saber como trabajan las demás personas que utilizan este framework. Soy nuevo utilizando estas tecnologías, estoy usando Visual Studio con ASP.NET MVC 5 y Entity Framework y acabo de empezar un nuevo proyecto, estoy con la creación de la base de datos por code first, tengo por ejemplo dos modelos **Padre** e **Hijo**

**Padre.cs**

```
    public class Padre
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
    }

    public class PruebaDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Pruebas.Models.Padre> Padres { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Pruebas.Models.Hijo> Hijos { get; set; }


    }
```

Tengo a su vez el modelo de **Hijo.cs**, mis preguntas serian:

1- Estaria bien poner mis DbSets en una clase del modelo (Como lo tengo en el ejemplo) o deberia ponerlo todos juntos en otra clase especifica para crear las tablas (En un archivo aparte).

2-Puedo colocar los DbSets en otra parte que no sea en mi clase *PruebaDBContext* sin tener que volver a usar DbContext pero que no me cree otra base de datos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por orden en tus clases te recomiendo crear tu contexto (con sus dbSet) en otra clase aparte con el fin de que sea escalable y que la entidad padre o la entidad hjo esten separadas y ordenadas en tu projecto. Con respecto a lo de la base de datos, no hay lio, solo te va a crear el o los contextos que definas.

Es importante aclarar que si en tu clase ya tienes un using asi:

```
    using System.Data.Entity;
```

No seria necesario que tus dbset vayan asi de largos:

```
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<....
```

Espero te sirva!